# Как переходить по листам в Excel документе из Delphi?

Tags: delphi, excel

Есть один файл в экселе там грубо говоря отчет по форме X. В самой программе в определенных полях (например TEdit) я заполняю данные которые должны замениться в файле в определенной ячейке в определенном листе (листов всего 11). Примерно понял как сделать это в активном листе:

```
Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\1.xls');
Excel.Range['F7']:='Привет';
Excel.save;
Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close;
Excel.Application.Quit;
```

Но как сделать в остальных листах? (или может я не так делаю, или может можно каким то более удобным не стандартным компонентом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
WorkSheet := Excel.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets['Лист1'];
WorkSheet.Cells[1,1]:='Пока';
```

Установите справку в офисе для VBA, там описана иерархия классов и методов. Все довольно прозрачно.

Comment: Ясно а есть толковая документация на это?
или хотя бы вот напиши как тогда после всех изменений, правильно сохранить всё, закрыть а потом открыть сам файл уже в Excel'e(хотя последнее сам понял как)

Comment: Откройте Excel. Нажмите Alt-F11. Дальше F1 и там Excel Object Reference (об этой справке говорил, раньше ее ставить надо было при установке офиса, сейчас хэлп доступен онлайн, проще стало).

Можете там же написать макрос, отладить его. потом в delphi перенести.

ЗЫ прошу прощея, пропустил ваш комментарий, сразу не ответил.